# dev-clean folder of LibriSpeecch Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, speech-recognition, transfer-learning

I am working on **LibriSpeech** Dev-Clean Dataset.
I am not able to understand the structure of the dataset.
I did come to know that Directories like 84, 1272 etc. under the dev-clean folder represent the ID of the speakers.
But what does sub-folders represent?

I meant if we look inside 1272 directory under the dev-clean folder, It is again divided into 3 folders i.e. - 128104, 135031, 141231.

This seems to be ambiguous to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Librispeech is made from the audiobooks by certain amount of speakers. 1272 is the speaker ID. 128104, 135031, 141231 are book IDs.
inside each folder there are recordings relevant to certain book.